# Azure ADF Alerts exclude specific activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-alerts

I have a pipeline with a conditional activity that sometimes shows errors on a look-up but is designed to continue and complete. I only want to show errors when the whole pipeline fails via the alerting. I'm getting an error alert for each activity failure which is how it's set up but for this pipeline I would like to exclude that activity only.
is it possible to name that activity somehow in a exclusion list?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting an error alert for each activity failure which is how it's set up but for this pipeline I would like to exclude that activity only.

**You cannot exclude alert for any Particular activity** else you can set alert for a particular activity.

**As you mention in the question your pipeline contains such activity that might fail but pipeline runs successfully. In that situation you can set trigger for whole pipeline failure sot that alert would trigger if pipeline failed to execute\complete not if pipeline completed successfully**.

**Example:**

[image]